# Finding a kernel of a linear map.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have been trying to solve this question and I think that I have reached a correct solution, which is:
$\ker(T)=\{(\alpha,0)\mid\alpha\in K^2\}$ and $\text{im}(T)=K$, however I don't really know how to conduct a formal proof for that. Have you got any suggestions? It would be greatly appreciated.

> Find the image and kernel of the linear map $T\colon K^2\to K^2$
>   defined by $T(x, y)=(y, 0)$.

Comment: $x=$ ANYTHING, $y=0$ .... it's hard to explain how because look at it!

Comment: What happens when you try to apply the definitions of *image* and *kernel* of a linear transformation?

Comment: So using the definition http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Linear_map we can define "kernel" as the subset of the domain of a function which maps to the element we identify as the "identity" in the codomain of the function. Which is 0. So kernel = ANYTHING which maps to $(0,0)$, in your case $(y,0)=(0,0)$ so we see $y=0$ and any $x$ will do. Thus the $x$ axis is the kernel

Comment: Thank you Alec for this suggestion, that's very clever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution for $\ker T$ is correct.

Note, though, that $K$ is not a subset of $K^2$, so it simply makes no sense to say that $\text{im } T = K$. It is true that (in this case) $\text{im } T$ is isomorphic to $K$, but $K^2$ has many subspaces that are: We must specify explicitly which!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct, apart from the fact that $\alpha$ needs to be in $K$, not $K^2$, since $K^2=\{(a,b) : a\in K, b\in K\}$.

Then it remains to show that any element of the form $(\alpha,0)$ is in the kernel.

We do this by computing $T((\alpha,0))=(0,0)$ for all $\alpha\in K$. This proves the kernel.

Then the for the image, we see that im($T$)=$\{(b,0):b\in K\}$. This is isomorphic to $K$ as a set, but not actually the same set as $K$.

Comment: Thank you! But what if we omitted some elements in kernel when we decided what kernel is. Then we will just prove that these elements are in kernel, but how to prove that no other elements are in the kernel?

Comment: The only elements that are not of the form $(a,0)$, must be of the form $(a,b)$ for $a,b\in K$ where $b\neq 0$. Then do $T(a,b)=(b,0)$ which doesn't equal $(0,0)$ since we said that $b\neq 0$. This shows that $(a,b)$ is not in the kernel when $b\neq 0$. Does that answer your question?